# Collatz conjecture

Tags: javascript, dom, collatz

I am trying to make the Collatz conjecture in JS but I have a problem and I do not understand it.
When I click on the button it return me 0, can someone help me please?

My js code:

```
let input   = document.getElementById('nombre');
let btn     = document.getElementById('submit');
let output  = document.getElementById('output');
let coups;

let nombre = input.value;

function conjecture() {
    do {
        if (nombre%2 === 0) {
            nombre /= 2;
            output.innerHTML += nombre + '<br>';
            coups ++;
        } else {
            nombre *= 3;
            nombre ++;
            output.innerHTML += nombre + '<br>';
            coups++;   
        }
    } while (nombre>1);

    output.innerHtml += `La courbe a atterit en ${coups} coups.<br>`; 
}

btn.addEventListener('click', conjecture);
```

Comment: `innerHtml` is not a property. You mean `innerHTML`.

Comment: what is the input type in the html

Comment: You redirect me to another question but my problem is not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the value before the user has had a chance to enter a number.

```
let nombre = input.value;
```

Make sure that line is *inside* your method which is called on `click`

```
function conjecture() {
     let nombre = input.value;
     ... rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all n positive integer values return to integer 1 for the following system of complex equation:

5n +1 if n=odd
n/2 if n=even 
Not all n positive integers return to 1, only the values represented return to 1.
 For the 5+1 complex system under the odd and even conditions above, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcy9S.jpg)